# Definition of the space of a repeated game

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, self-study, dynamic-games

I want to define the space of a stochastic game and it confuses me a lot, so I want someone to check please the space $\Theta$ that I define at the end and how could I define the sigma algebra of this space. So I will give a generic framework of the game like an algorithm that runs in many stages, this is the idea of the multistage games as well.

Imagine that the following algorithm runs:

- at t=1, an element $(\omega,s^0)$ is realized, namely $h_0=(\omega,s^0)\in H^0$
- for this $h_0$, the elements $m$ and $r$ run for $K$ rounds, namely think of a loop of an arbitrary procedure that gives in its beginning $r_{1,1}\in R(h_{0,1})$ and $m_{1,1}\in M(h_{0,1})$ (for the first repetition), $(r_{1,k})_{k=1}^2\in R(h_{0,2})$ and $(m_{1,k})_{k=1}^2\in M(h_{0,2})$ (second repetition) and at the end ($k-$th repetition), the elements $(r_{1,k})_{k=1}^K\in R(h_{0,k})$ and $(m_{1,k})_{k=1}^K\in M(h_{0,k})$
- when the loop ends, based on $(r_{1,k})_{k=1}^K$ and $(m_{1,k})_{k=1}^K$, the algorithm gives back an action, say $a_1\left(h_{0,k},\left((r_{1,k})_{k=1}^K,(m_{1,k})_{k=1}^K\right)\right)\in\Delta(A(h_{0,k}))$ and hence a new element $s^1$ emerges, so we denote $h_1=(\omega,s^0,(a_1,s_1))\in H_1$ and the procedure takes place again for $t=2$ and so on.,

In other words after this procedure is realized, for t=1, we obtain the following element
$\theta_1=\left(h_0,\left(r_{1,k},m_{1,k}\right)_{k=1}^K,a_1\right)$. Likewise we can take

- In $t=2$, $\theta_2=\left(h_1,\left(r_{2,k},m_{2,k}\right)_{k=1}^K,a_2\right)$ and $h_2=(\omega,s^0,(a_1,s_1),(a_1,s_2))\in H_1$ and in stage $t=3$, $\theta_2=\left(h_2,\left(r_{3,k},m_{3,k}\right)_{k=1}^K,a_3\right)$ and so on.

$\textbf{Question 1:}$ Can the measurable space of the element $\theta_t$ be denoted as the product space

$$\Theta=H^{t-1}\times M(h_{t-1,k})\times R(h_{t-1,k})\times A(h_{t-1})\times \Omega$$?
What is the corresponding $\sigma-$algebra?

$\textbf{Question 2:}$ If the procedure is repeated for $t=T$, when $T\to +\infty$ then haw can the space of the elements be written?